# Is possible to get a twitter account age programatically?

Tags: twitter, tweets, tweetsharp

I want to code a twitter interface but I need to check programatically if the account wasn't created recently, to avoid bots and new users.

Is there a way via the API to get that information from a given username?

Comment: A quick glance at the [Twitter API docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users#Optional) tells me you can get an optional `created_at` property. Does that help answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Day of birth is not available via de Twitter-API and probably never will be. This is deemed sensitive information by Twitter.

Here are all user-fields you can retrieve:
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-id

edit: You can retrieve the 'created_at'-field to get the creation date (I believe as a timestamp)

Comment: I don't need the user age, but the account age, meaning how long ago it was created.

Comment: Follow the link in my previous response. You can retrieve the created_at field from the user-field.